# Getting a value calculating a column with same column

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have been trying to get a single result. but im getting multiple in return.
Note that for corrections in the applications, i need the OrgId to know which Row has to be corrected visually. without altering the original row. So im trying to calculate the new value in a query field.

Wanted result is when I ask record 1 from table, i get a truevalue of -1
But the results are found below. I cant use 2 results as it will give me the error of "mulitple rows have been returned as a result of a subquery"

My table: table

```
Id |Amount|OrgId|
---|------|-----|
1  |10    |     |
2  |-8    |1    |
3  |-2    |1    |
4  |-1    |1    |
5  |2     |     |
```

as for my query:

```
select
  case
    when not tableb.OrgId is null and exists(select 1 from table where OrgId = X then
      (select tablea.amount + sum(tableb.amount))
    else
      (select tablea.amount)
    end as trueamount
from table as tablea, table as tableb
where tablea.id = X
group by tableb.OrgId, tablea.amount
```

X references any used integer

When X = 1 the result is:

```
trueamount
----
-1
10
```

When X = 5 the result is

```
trueamount
----
2
2
```

I have tried altering the query in various manners, but im either getting 2 rows as results with a blank, totally wrong numbers, or no results at all.

Any idea how to single out the result i need?

Comment: What is expected result from your example table ?

Comment: in case X is 1, the expected result = -1, in case X is 5, the expected result = 2

Comment: So when X not exists in `OrgId` column, then you need  Amount `where Id = X`. Is this correct ?

Comment: yes. thats right

Comment: Got my solution, given to me by my senior who wasnt available yet until now. I have been looking for a solution for half a day :(

    select (amount+(select coalesce(sum(amount), 0) from table where Id=OrgId) as true value
    from table
    where ID = X